# Assign ID or dictionary efficiently for multiple values that formed a grid in a large coordinates XY tuples for python?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, coordinates

I'm quite new in using Python. Assuming that i have a list of coordinates tuples that looks like this :

```
[(0.5, 3.5), (0.5, 4.0), (0.5, 4.5), (0.5, 5.0), (1.0, 3.5), (1.0, 4.0), (1.0, 4.5), (1.0, 5.0), (1.5, 3.5), (1.5, 4.0), (1.5, 4.5), (1.5, 5.0), (2.0, 3.5), (2.0, 4.0), (2.0, 4.5), (2.0, 5.0)]
```

the output using `matplotlib` graph looks like this :
[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUlni.png)

The real data is much more larger than this one actually. So my goal is to assign a Grid ID for each tuple that formed a grid in cartesian coordinate. The example Grid ID is like this :

Grid 1 : (0.5, 3.5), (0.5, 4.0), (1.0, 3.5), (1.0, 4.0)

Grid 2 : (1.0, 3.5), (1.0, 4.0), (1.5, 3.5), (1.5, 4.0)
.
.

Grid 9 : (1.5, 4.5), (1.5, 5.0), (2.0, 4.5), (2.0, 5.0)

I understand how to create this manually using `dictionary` method in python, but because the data is large i believe there is a more efficient way to create the Grid ID automatically. Is there any efficient way or method in Pyhthon to create the ID automatically? Any help or similar answered question would be appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: How exactly are you grouping the `tuples` into Grid IDs? What's the relationship between `(0.5, 3.5)` and `(1.0, 4.0)`? By "grid" do you mean a "box" in the Cartesian "grid"?

Comment: it is an XY coordinates , its like this [(x1, y1) , (x2,y2) ,....]